# Sent to multiple email swiftmail php

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

> Uncaught Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [angga.q.suwito@gmail.com', 'stand.last41@gmail.com', 'gamingid41@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php:355 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(272): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->assertValidAddress('angga.q.suwito@...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(117): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->normalizeMailboxes(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(74): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setNameAddresses(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderFactory.php(61): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->s in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\swiftmailer\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php on line 355

```
<?php

require_once 'swiftmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

$email[] = 'angga.q.suwito@gmail.com';
$email[] = 'stand.last41@gmail.com';
$email[] = 'gamingid41@gmail.com';

$semuaemail = implode("', '",$email); 

$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername('gamingid41@gmail.com')->setPassword('56865681');

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message('Weekly Hours');
$message
   ->setFrom(['gamingid41@gmail.com' => 'My Name'])
   ->setTo([$semuaemail => 'Recipient'])
   ->setSubject('Coba dang sejadi')
   ->setBody('bukan kaleng kaleng', 'text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);

echo "Berhasil terkirim";

?>
```

Comment: You can directly give you array in `setTo` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828531/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-swiftmailer).

Comment: or change $semuaemail = implode("', '",$email);  to $semuaemail = "'" . implode("', '",$email) . "'";